# How to handle multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array that inside it has several other arrays.

What I need is to find the array that has an object with `name: "tax-payer-identification"`. Change the variable's value `required: true` to `false`.

But the problem is that it's an array of arrays and I don't know how to manipulate it, change the variable value, and return the array to be used.

Can you tell me how can I do this? Thank you very much for any help.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { data } from "./data";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const getData = () => {
    data.map((item) => item.map((item2) => console.log(item2)));
  };

  console.log(getData());

  return <div>App</div>;
};

export default App;
```

```js
export const data = [
  [{
    // some data
  }],
  [{
      // some data
    },
    {
      // some data
    }
  ],
  [{
    // some data
  }],
  [{
    name: "tax-payer-identification",
    type: "text",
    regex: "^.{0,20}$",
    inputName: "vatNumber",
    required: true,
    maxLength: 20,
    minLength: 0
  }],
  [{
    // some data
  }],
  [{
    // some data
  }],
  [{
      // some data
    },
    {
      // some data
    }
  ],
  [{
      // some data
    },
    {
      // some data
    }
  ]
];
```

Comment: try using `flatMap` to get everything into one level and then return an array in the callback that you map to it

Comment: but then how do I reverse array in the structure that was before?

Comment: Oh right, well then I guess good old nested looping should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that could possibly work:

```
const output = data.map(item => item.map(nested => {
    if (nested.name === "tax-payer-identification") {
        nested.required = true
    }
    return nested
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function would do the same and can be used when the `array` structure is not predictable:

```
const updateArray = (dataArray, updates = {}) => {
    let result = [];

    const updateApply = (objData) => {
        if (updates && Object.keys(updates).length > 0) {
            Object.keys(updates).map((key) => {
                if (objData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    objData[key] = updates[key];
                }
            });
        }

        return objData;
    };

    for (const index in dataArray) {
        if (Array.isArray(dataArray[index])) {
            result[index] = dataArray[index].map((e) => {
                return Array.isArray(e)
                    ? updateArray([...e], updates)
                    : updateApply(e);
            });
        } else {
            result[index] = updateApply(dataArray[index]);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Calling the function with the object(s) that need to be changed:

```
updateArray(data, { require: false });
```